# aggregate function Count usage with groupBy in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to make multiple operations in one line of code in pySpark,
and not sure if that's possible for my case.

My intention is not having to save the output as a new dataframe.

My current code is rather simple:

```
encodeUDF = udf(encode_time, StringType())
new_log_df.cache().withColumn('timePeriod', encodeUDF(col('START_TIME')))
  .groupBy('timePeriod')
  .agg(
    mean('DOWNSTREAM_SIZE').alias("Mean"),
    stddev('DOWNSTREAM_SIZE').alias("Stddev")
  )
  .show(20, False)
```

And my intention is to add `count()` after using `groupBy`, to get, well, the count of records matching each value of **`timePeriod`** column, printed\shown as output.

When trying to use `groupBy(..).count().agg(..)` I get exceptions.

**Is there any way to achieve both `count()` and `agg()`**.show() prints, without splitting code to two lines of commands, e.g. :

```
new_log_df.withColumn(..).groupBy(..).count()
new_log_df.withColumn(..).groupBy(..).agg(..).show()
```

Or better yet, for getting a merged output to `agg.show()` output - An extra column which states the counted number of records matching the row's value. e.g.:

```
timePeriod | Mean | Stddev | Num Of Records
    X      | 10   |   20   |    315
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`count()` can be used inside `agg()` as `groupBy` expression is same.

## With Python

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

new_log_df.cache().withColumn("timePeriod", encodeUDF(new_log_df["START_TIME"])) 
  .groupBy("timePeriod")
  .agg(
     func.mean("DOWNSTREAM_SIZE").alias("Mean"), 
     func.stddev("DOWNSTREAM_SIZE").alias("Stddev"),
     func.count(func.lit(1)).alias("Num Of Records")
   )
  .show(20, False)
```

[pySpark SQL functions doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions)

## With Scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ //for count()

new_log_df.cache().withColumn("timePeriod", encodeUDF(col("START_TIME"))) 
  .groupBy("timePeriod")
  .agg(
     mean("DOWNSTREAM_SIZE").alias("Mean"), 
     stddev("DOWNSTREAM_SIZE").alias("Stddev"),
     count(lit(1)).alias("Num Of Records")
   )
  .show(20, false)
```

`count(1)` will count the records by first column which is equal to `count("timePeriod")`

## With Java

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

new_log_df.cache().withColumn("timePeriod", encodeUDF(col("START_TIME"))) 
  .groupBy("timePeriod")
  .agg(
     mean("DOWNSTREAM_SIZE").alias("Mean"), 
     stddev("DOWNSTREAM_SIZE").alias("Stddev"),
     count(lit(1)).alias("Num Of Records")
   )
  .show(20, false)
```

Comment: is there any way in dataframe  to count all the records by partition wise and aggregate it to final count , if so how ?

Comment: you mean, something similar to `reduceBy` ?

Comment: A minor syntax comment: I am a big fan of the dict syntax in Python, e.g. `.agg({"X: "sum", "Y": "sum", "Z": "sum", "blah": "count"})`, this works really nice with `.withColumn("blah", lit(1))` - there might be a better way, but I have not found it (yet!).

Comment: Your code works beautifully! Is there a way to use alias and rename the columns? Because right now the result comes out in columns names like sum(X), sum(Z), ...

Comment: What does that lit(1) do?

Comment: @RFAI: `lit(1)` means the first column in the result which is `timePeriod `.

Comment: I dont get why Scala has a built in 'count' function for this agg() function, but python doesn't . Just adds to my frustrations with Python.