# How to group by columns and aggregate rest of the columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mean

I am new in pyspark, so I would be thankful if anyone can help to fix the problem.

Suppose that I have a dataframe in pyspark as follows:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   A|2001|   2|   5|   6|
|   A|2001|   3|   6|  10|
|   A|2001|   3|   6|  10|
|   A|2002|   4|   5|   2|
|   B|2001|   2|   9|   4|
|   B|2001|   2|   4|   3|
|   B|2001|   2|   3|   4|
|   B|2001|   3|  95|   7|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I want to get the mean of the `col4` if the corresponding values in `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are the same and then get rid of the rows with the repeated values in the first 3 columns.

For example, the values of the `col1`, `col2`, `col3` in the two first column are same, so, we want to eliminate one of them and update the value of `col4` as the mean of `col4` and `col5`. The result should be:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   A|2001|   2| 4.5|   7|
|   A|2001|   3|   6|  10|
|   A|2002|   4|   5|   2|
|   B|2001|   2|5.33|3.67|
|   B|2001|   3|  95|   7|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

The similar question has been ask but in pandas dataframe. This question is asked in pyspark dataframe

Comment: IIUC `df.groupby("col1", "col2", "col3").agg(f.mean("col4"), f.mean("col5"))` where `f` is defined by `import pyspark.sql.functions as f`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark:How to calculate avg and count in a single groupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632126/pysparkhow-to-calculate-avg-and-count-in-a-single-groupby)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Creating the said `DataFrame` -

```
values = [('A',2001,2,5,6),('A',2001,2,4,8),('A',2001,3,6,10),('A',2002,4,5,2),
          ('B',2001,2,9,4),('B',2001,2,4,3),('B',2001,2,3,4),('B',2001,3,95,7)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   A|2001|   2|   5|   6|
|   A|2001|   2|   4|   8|
|   A|2001|   3|   6|  10|
|   A|2002|   4|   5|   2|
|   B|2001|   2|   9|   4|
|   B|2001|   2|   4|   3|
|   B|2001|   2|   3|   4|
|   B|2001|   3|  95|   7|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**Step 2:** Aggregating the column `col4` & `col5`.

```
df = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).agg(avg('col4').alias('col4'),avg('col5').alias('col5'))
df.show()
+----+----+----+-----------------+------------------+
|col1|col2|col3|             col4|              col5|
+----+----+----+-----------------+------------------+
|   A|2001|   3|              6.0|              10.0|
|   A|2002|   4|              5.0|               2.0|
|   B|2001|   2|5.333333333333333|3.6666666666666665|
|   A|2001|   2|              4.5|               7.0|
|   B|2001|   3|             95.0|               7.0|
+----+----+----+-----------------+------------------+
```